# Span columns with a 'center' environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, two-column

For the question [How to place a "banner image" at the top of a paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53966/how-to-place-a-banner-image-at-the-top-of-a-paper/53968#53968) the solution was to use a `center` environment to create a non-floating figure:

```
\documentclass{acmtog}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,format=hang]{subfig} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\captiontype[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\BannerFigSize{.25}
\begin{center}
\captiontype{figure}
\subfloat[a.]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  \label{fig:banner:scene}
  }
\subfloat[b.]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  \label{fig:banner:strokes}
  }
\caption{Our algorithms.}
\label{fig:banner}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, unlike `figure*`, `center*` is not a valid operator to span columns. Is there a way to make this `center` environment span two columns?

Comment: This isn't really an issue of `center` or the other content. You simply need to switch to one-column mode for the banner. See [How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28109/2975), which should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't place something over two columns in the middle of a page, just at the top or bottom. Here you can use one of the solutions given for [How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28109/2975), i.e. use the optional argument of `\twocolumn` to add double-column material at the beginning of the two-column page:

You need to place the `\maketitle` in the `\twocolumn[..]` as well, but it uses 
`\twocolumn` itself, which will cause an error. You can avoid this by locally redefining `\twocolumn` so that the inner one is ignore.

```
\documentclass{acmtog}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,format=hang]{subfig} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\captiontype[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My paper}
\author{Me {\upshape and} My Friend
\affil{Affiliation}}
\acmVolume{VV}
\acmNumber{N}
\acmYear{2012}
\acmMonth{April}
\acmArticleNum{XXX}
\acmdoi{10.1145/XXXXXXX.YYYYYYY}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{%
\renewcommand\twocolumn[1][]{#1}%
\maketitle
\def\BannerFigSize{.25}
\begin{center}
\captiontype{figure}
\subfloat[a.]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  \label{fig:banner:scene}
  }
\subfloat[b.]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  \label{fig:banner:strokes}
  }
\caption{Our algorithms.}
\label{fig:banner}
\end{center}%
}]
\begin{bottomstuff}
Authors' addresses: 
\end{bottomstuff}
\lipsum% dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example works. However, when I add the rest of the preamble stuff to the document (to try to add the image after the title), the image gets pushed to the second page: http://pastebin.com/LSi24uKZ

Any idea what has changed?

Comment: @DavidDoria: This is because `\twocolumn` will force a new page. Try to add all other titling code into the `\twocolumn[..]`.

Comment: If I move \maketitle into the \twocolumn, I get the error "Float(s) lost. }]". I'm also not sure how the \begin{bottomstuff} environment works - it seems to matter where this is placed as well.

Comment: @DavidDoria: See my update. The issue was that `\maketitle` include `\twocolumn` itself. The `bottomstuff` should be directly after the `\twocolumn[..]` before the actual text.