# Input a figure between title and body in twocolumn form

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I'm using a LaTeX to write a small paper using CVPR template.

I'd like to put a figure between my title+name and body(which consists with two columns) like many CVPR papers do, but I don't find the way to do that.

I tried:

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{2in} \rule{.9\linewidth}{0pt}}
\end{center}
   \caption{some caption..}
\label{fig:short}
\end{figure*}
```

But it turned out figure-star only displays it's figure at the top of *next* page,
and when I just use figure like `\begin{figure}[htb]`, it's only located one of those two columns.

Does anyone know how to put a long figure between my title+name and body context?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, not just a code fragment. You can't have a double-column material in the middle of the page, because it is not possible to split two-columns in half. This seems to be very similar to [Span columns with a 'center' environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53984/2975), just with a different class.

Comment: Note that you [shouldn't use `center` but `\centering` inside `figure`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651). Also you can now use `\includegraphics[..]{example-image}` to represent your image. See [New support package for MWEs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2470/2975)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The title is also set in double-column format and you can't have two of these in a row. You need to place the title and the (non-floating) figure into one `\twocolumn[{..}]` macro. The problem is that `\maketitle` already uses `\twocolumn`, but this can actually be redefined as a non-op.

This is analog to my solution for [Span columns with a 'center' environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53984/2975). I post it here again because it's for a different style and many beginners will have issues adapting the other post to CVPR.

I like to mention that having a figure directly below the title might not be a good style.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{cvpr}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text only
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\def\cvprPaperID{}% Remove and set correct ID

\title{Test}
\author{A. Tester}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{%
\renewcommand\twocolumn[1][]{#1}%
\maketitle
\begin{center}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Test caption}
\end{center}%
}]

\Blindtext% Replace with your real text

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This works how it is supposed to be but it prints out some error when I compile it. (still make the result though). it says: "Undefined Control Sequence }]" Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, not really. Can you post a minimized version of the code somewhere?

Comment: Spent many agonizing hours trying to figure this out until I found your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since this question appears pretty high on search results, and this might be exactly something a SIGCHI template user may be looking for, here's an option that works on the SIGCHI template. (http://www.sigchi.org/publications/chipubform/sigchi-papers-latex-template/view)

```
\teaser{
\centering
\subfloat[Subfigure caption A\label{subfig:fig4a}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.15\textwidth]{FigSub4a} %standard image inclusion call
}   ~
\subfloat[Subfigure caption B\label{subfig:fig4b}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.15\textwidth]{FigSub4b}
}   ~
\subfloat[Subfigure caption C\label{subfig:fig4c}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.15\textwidth]{FigSub4b}
}
\caption{Teaser pic}
\label{fig:figure3}
}
```

This only works because of the following text inside the sigchi.cls file:

```
% [jdf] create a \teaser command for adding a figure in title page
\newcommand{\chi@empty}{}
\newcommand{\chi@teaser}{}
\newcommand{\teaser}[1]{\renewcommand{\chi@teaser}{#1}}

\newlength{\teaserspace}
\setlength{\teaserspace}{0.25in}
%  [jdf] end teaser
```

I can only presume that [jdf] = Jean-Daniel Fetke who edited this template on Aug 28, 2011.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is often preferable to post a complete minimal document demonstrating the use of the code, rather than just code snippets.  Perhaps you could update your answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on the 2018 CHI sigchi.cls template. No errors or warnings, but the figures just don't show up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For CVPR  \twocolumn works

The IEEE ICRA IROS template, it does not

This code below works in my case for IEEE conference template

% after make title insert this

```
\begin{strip}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering
\vspace{-100pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{image/figure1_2un.pdf}
\captionof{figure}{this is your captions.}
\label{figurelabel}
\end{minipage}
\end{strip}


\begin{abstract}
```

[image]